# Who can invite new members into an organization

Tags: trello-organization

I have an organization and would like to avoid that the organization members invite new members that are not supposed to be invited to this organization. Is there a way to make sure that only, for instance, the admins can invite new members to the organization and therefore keep control of who is joining the organization?